# Checking substring in 8086 ASM

Tags: strings, assembly

I have tried like this to check a substring in a mainstring in 8086.  Is there any shorter way of doing this?  My implementation seems lengthy.

```
DATA SEGMENT
STR1 DB 'MADAM'
LEN1 DW ($-STR1);       storing the length of STR1
STR2 DB 'MADAA'
LEN2 DW ($-STR2);       stroing the length of STR2
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT

LEA SI, STR1
LEA DI, STR2
MOV DX, LEN1
MOV CX, LEN2
CMP CX, DX;             comparing main & substring length
JA EXIT;                if substring size is bigger than there is no chance to be found it in main string
JE SAMELENGTH;          if main & sub string both have same length the we can compare them directly
JB FIND;                general case (substring length < mainstring length): we can apply our main process                 

SAMELENGTH:
        CLD
        REPE CMPSB
        JNE RED
        JMP GREEN

FIND:        
        MOV AL, [SI];   storing the ascii value of current character of mainstring 
        MOV AH, [DI];   storing the ascii value of current character of substring
        CMP AL,AH;      comparing both character
        JE CHECK;       
        JNE NOTEQL

NOTEQL:
        INC SI;         if both character don't match then we would point to the next char of main string
        DEC DX;         DX keeps track of how many character of mainstring is left to process
        CMP DX, 0000H;  checking if there are any character left in the main string for further comparison 
        JE RED;         if no character is left in main string then obviously the substring doesn't exists in main string
        JMP FIND

CHECK:
        MOV CX, LEN2;   CX is used internally for REPE CMPSB. So storing length of the substring in CX would limit the number of characters for comparison to exact length of substring.
        ;               For example to compare between "madam" & "ada" we need to compare *ada* portion of main string with substring ada, no more, no less     
        MOV SP, SI;     storing the index of current character of main string so if the following REPE CMPSB find mismatch then the process can be started over from the next character of main string (SEE line 1 of TEMPRED) by going to TEMPRED > FIND
        ADD SP, 0001H
        CLD
        REPE CMPSB
        JNE TEMPRED
        JMP GREEN

TEMPRED:;               substring not found starting from the current character of main string, but it is possible to find match if we start from next character in main string
        MOV SI,SP;      going to the next character of main string (after REPE CMPSB of CHECK segment)
        DEC DX
        LEA DI, STR2;   reloading substring index in DI (after REPE CMPSB of CHECK segment)
        JMP FIND;       if a character matches but the following substring mismatches in main string then we start over the same process from the next character of main string by going to FIND segment         

GREEN:  
        MOV BX, 0001H;  substring found
        JMP EXIT


RED:    
        MOV BX, 0000H;  substring not found
        JMP EXIT

EXIT:         
    CODE ENDS
    END
    RET
```

Comment: specify the assembler name/version. Is it nasm,masm,fasm,as.. ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of things that could be improved with this code.  I hope you find these suggestions helpful.

### Specify which assembler

Unlike C or Python, there are a great many variations in assembler syntax, even for the same architecture, such as the x86 of this code.  Generally, it's useful to note which assembler, which target processor and which OS (if any) in the comments at the top of the file.  In this case, it looked most like 16-bit TASM, so that's the compiler I used to test this code.

### Use an `ASSUME` directive

The code would not assemble for me until I added an `ASSUME` directive. The `ASSUME` directive doesn't actually generate any code.  It simply specifies which assumptions the assembler should make when generating the output.  It also helps human readers of your code understand the intended context.  In this particular case, I added this line just after the `CODE SEGMENT` declaration:

```
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA, ES:DATA
```

The `CS` and `DS` assumptions are obvious, but the `ES` assumption is less so. However, the code uses the `CMPSB` instruction and based on the context, this means an implicit assumption that `ES` also points to the `DATA` segment.  In my case, (emulated 16-bit DOS), I had to add a few statements to the start of the code to actually load the DS and ES segment registers appropriately.

### Avoid instructions outside any segment

The `EXIT` code currently looks like this:

```
EXIT:         
        CODE ENDS
        END
        RET
```

The problem is that the `CODE ENDS` closes the `CODE` segment and the `END` directive tells the assembler that there is no more code and thus the `RET` instruction may or may not be assembled, and may or may not actually be placed in the `CODE` segment.  You probably meant instead to do this:

```
EXIT:         
        RET
        CODE ENDS
        END
```

### Eliminate convoluted branching

Avoid needless branching.  They make your code harder to read and slower to execute.  For example, the code currently has this:

```
        JA EXIT
        JE SAMELENGTH
        JB FIND

SAMELENGTH:
        CLD
        REPE CMPSB
        JNE RED
        JMP GREEN
        ; ... code elided
GREEN:  
        MOV BX, 0001H;  substring found
        JMP EXIT

RED:    
        MOV BX, 0000H;  substring not found
        JMP EXIT
EXIT:
```

This could be very much simplified:

```
        JA EXIT
        JB FIND
        ;  fall through to same length
SAMELENGTH:
        XOR BX,BX      ; assume string not found
        CLD
        REPE CMPSB
        JNE EXIT
        INC BX         ; indicate that string was found
EXIT:
```

There are a number of such simplifications possible with little effort.

### Know your instruction set

The code currently has this set of instructions

```
        DEC DX
        CMP DX, 0000H
        JE RED
```

However, the `DEC` instruction already sets the `Z` flag, so the `CMP` instruction is not needed.

### Use `REPNE SCASB` as appropriate

The code at the location `FIND` is largely the same as would have been done by using `REPNE SCASB`.  The only difference is in which registers are used.  The code you have isn't necessarily wrong, but it could probably be shorter.

### Avoid using `SP` as a general register

Just after `CHECK`, the code saves a copy of the pointer (not an index as the comment falsely claims) to the `SP` register.  However, `SP` is a stack pointer, so this code can only be used in an environment in which the stack is not used.  That could be the case, but it makes the code much less portable to code it that way, especially because the `AX` or `BX` registers could just as easily have been used here.

### Consider using standard length lines

The comments in the code are very long and the semicolon is right after the instruction. Neither of these things are necessarily wrong, but they are different from the usual convention which is to align the semicolon character in some column and making sure that lines are no more than 72 characters long (some use 78).

Answer (score 3):

We are determining if a substring appears in a string. This algorithm/code snippet is written for x86_64 Intel on Linux with NASM. It's quite shorter but because of the `repe cmpsb`, it's certainly not the fastest.

```
section .data

    ; the string
    string:       db "this is the string we are searching in"
    stringlength: equ $-string

    ; the substring
    substring:    db "string we are searching"
    substringlength: equ $-substring        


    mov     rsi, string                    ; pointer to string in RSI
    mov     rdx, stringlength              ; length of string in RDX

    ; Subtract substring length to prevent looking beyond the string length,
    ; We can also check here if the substring fits in the string.
    ; If not we never can find the substring in the string

    sub     rdx, substringlength
    cmp     rdx, 0
    jl      .@@notfound

    ; enter the compare loop
.@@repeat:    
    mov     rdi, substring                 ; pointer to substring in RDI
    mov     rcx, substringlength           ; length substring in RCX (loop counter)
    cld
    repe        cmpsb                      ; compare string at rdi with length rcx with string in rsi
    jz          .@@found                   ; if zero flag then substring is found within string, exit loop

    ; substring is not found yet, put substring pointer at begin of substring

    dec         rdx                        ; decrement length of string
    and         rdx, rdx                   ; check remaining length to search in
    jnz         .@@repeat                  ; remaining length non-zero, repeat

.@@notfound:
    ; else, substring wasn't found, exit loop
    ; substring not found actions

.@@found:
    ; substring found actions
    ; rsi has address to start of substring+the length of the substring
    ; subtracting the start of the string we can calculate the offset (or index) in the string where substring starts

    sub         rsi, substringlength
```

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, the algorithm posted by **@Agguro** **would not match `ABC` against `AABC`**, as it always "eats up" at least substring length characters from the main string. This can be corrected as below.

```
section .data

    ; the string
    string:       db "this is the string we are searching in"
    stringlength: equ $-string

    ; the substring
    substring:    db "string we are searching"
    substringlength: equ $-substring        

    mov     rsi, string                    ; pointer to string in RSI
    mov     rdx, stringlength              ; length of string in RDX

    ; Subtract substring length to prevent looking beyond the string length,
    ; We can also check here if the substring fits in the string.
    ; If not we never can find the substring in the string

    sub     rdx, substringlength
    cmp     rdx, 0
    jl      .@@notfound

    ; enter the compare loop
.@@repeat:    
    mov     rdi, substring                 ; pointer to substring in RDI
    mov     rcx, substringlength           ; length substring in RCX (loop counter)
    cld
    mov         rax,rsi                    ; save rsi
    repe        cmpsb                      ; compare string at rdi with length rcx with string in rsi
    jz          .@@found                   ; if zero flag then substring is found within string, exit loop

    ; substring is not found yet, put substring pointer at begin of substring

    inc         rax                        ; increment rax to proceed one character in string
    mov         rsi,rax                    ; restore the modified rsi value from rax
    dec         rdx                        ; decrement length of string
    and         rdx, rdx                   ; check remaining length to search in
    jnz         .@@repeat                  ; remaining length non-zero, repeat

.@@notfound:
    ; else, substring wasn't found, exit loop
    ; substring not found actions

.@@found:
    ; substring found actions
    ; rsi has address to start of substring+the length of the substring
    ; subtracting the start of the string we can calculate the offset (or index) in the string where substring starts

    sub         rsi, substringlength
```

Not directly related: also, depending on the use cases for the function, comparing `rdx` (the remaining string length) with `substringlength` might be worth it as an optimization just above line `and rdx, rdx`. This is only worth it if both the string and substring are very long, but close in length. It would on average slow down the match if the string is very long, but the substring - very short.